# Radeon Pro 580 and Blender 2.8

Tags: gpu

I know about the whole "stop using Blender on Mac thing" but still -I do. I use a iMac 27" 2017 with Mojave and have a Radeon Pro 580 8GB GPU -and it works really fine with 2.79b! But now, when I try the 2.8 beta, no GPU is found. As far as I can tell the Radeon Pro 580 has OpenGL 4.6.

Will my GPU work in later builds?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128693/mac-pro-tower-sapphire-radeon-rx580-is-really-really-slow and answers below.

Answer (score 2):

Its not the GPU's Fault. More like Apple's support for OpenGL/CL.

the RX 580s run very well under Windows and Linux. You can either use dualboot or a Virtualmachine using HW Passtthru to use blender thru for example Linux with direct Hardware access to the gpu.

Regarding the second Question: You should mostly never render to Video directly. You may try a newer 2.8 Build or a different codec.

Answer (score 0):

I use an IBM PC with the Radeon RX 580 8GB GPU, Blender 2.8 recognizes it in the OpenCL Cycles part in the system preferences. I can render PNG with Eevee engine, but video files render is still a problem, need to get the 2.79 to get all png image sequence and create a video file.