# Unsupported Radeon VII eGPU rendering on MacOS and Blender 2.8 beta

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I installed a Radeon VII into the Razor Core X eGPU, hoping to increase rendering speeds in Cycles on a 2018 15" MacBook Pro (i9, 32gigs ram). The beta 2.8 2019-6-12 version shows the message, "No compatible GPUs found for path tracing. Cycles will render on the CPU." The stable 2.79b 2018-3-22 version allows me to select "AMD Radeon VII Compute Engine" in the OpenCL tab of User Preferences ... -> System, set Device to GPU Compute under Scene -> Render, and optimize my tile settings to 256x256 in Scene -> Render -> Performance. Will we have the same options with 2.8 when it's out of Beta. I'm a Blender newb, but a long time Maya user excited to switch to Blender 2.8, but I'll be stuck on 2.79b if my eGPU setup isn't supported :*( ... will it be?

Comment: Mac and Radeon are about the most problematic combination for blender. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/128693/1853  Do a search on this site for more posts like that. Consider having your computer boot on Linux or windows.